# Bokeh Gmap hide/unhide background

Tags: python, google-maps, bokeh

I have a Bokeh image made with patches onto a google map as background.

http://giove.units.it:5000

Is there a tool (or javascript code) to hide/unhide the background ? and is there way to save in png the background too ?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

As of Bokeh `0.11.1` (and soon to be `0.12`) there is no mechanism to hide the map portion. It seems like a reasonable feature though, an probably not terribly difficult to implement. I encourage you to submit a feature request on the project's [GitHub issue tracker](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues).

There *might* be some roundabout ways to do what you want currently, by setting `map_options` from a JS callback or something. But figuring that out would take discussion and experimentation and iteration, and StackOverflow is not very good for that kind of thing. I encourage you to bring the question to the project's [public mailing list](https://groups.google.com/a/continuum.io/forum/?pli=1#!forum/bokeh) where more of a back-and-forth dialogue is possible.

Comment: posted to Google's Group.

Comment: Google's Group topic https://groups.google.com/a/continuum.io/forum/?pli=1#!topic/bokeh/3EZCfjio-_Y